# How do I get corresponding x and y values in a stacked chart using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart that I designed.

SampleData used to populate the stacked chart is shown below.

```
    Task            Counter    TaskState
    BusinessTime    29         Completed
    BusinessTime    100        Started
    NewYorkTime     2          Completed
    NewYorkTime     49         Started
    DailyTimes      65         Outstanding
    DailyTimes      60         Completed
```

I want to be able to click on any of the chart items and see the breakdown for example, click on businessTime to see the total no completed.

How do I achieve that please?  I'm relatively new to chart controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was resolved using series.url method.
The xaxis value in the stacked chart was gotten via #ValX. This didn't work initially until i set the valuetype property of xaxis.

Thanks all